# How to fire local notifications one day before event is due Android

Tags: android

I have a native Android to-do app. I want to show local notifications to the user one day before an event starts.

I have checked the AlarmManager, Broadcast Receivers and Services but I don't have a clear understanding of them.

Can you point me in the right direction? I have to scan continously in my SQLite DB if I have events for tomorrow to inform the user, even when the app is not in the foreground.

Comment: You could try using a TimerTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule tasks easily with Java's TimerTask. I pulled the following code example from [this tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/what-is-timer-and-timertask-in-java-example-tutorial.html)

```
public class JavaReminder {
Timer timer;

public JavaReminder(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();  //At this line a new Thread will be created
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000); //delay in milliseconds
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ReminderTask is completed by Java timer");
        timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit
        //System.exit(0); //Stops the AWT thread (and everything else)
    }
}
//Do this in your launch activity, or a class specified in androidmanifest to run immediately
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Java timer is about to start");
    JavaReminder reminderBeep = new JavaReminder(5);
    System.out.println("Remindertask is scheduled with Java timer.");

}
```

}

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/what-is-timer-and-timertask-in-java-example-tutorial.html#ixzz3XCtfeJwc

Keeping track of time is actually not a trivial task. You don't need to keep looking at your sqlite database, just get it once and keep it up to date in your app. I recommend against using System time, because that may change; instead try pulling time from online. I recommend [joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for your time calculations.

Comment: If you want it to run when app is not active, you should run it in a service

Comment: This is something I've done before, but I just found this - Perhaps there is a better solution that mine using an AlarmManager http://vikinghammer.com/2012/04/22/android-use-alarmmanager-instead-of-a-service-with-a-timertask/

Comment: lol dude, I'm not gonna do the project for you. If you have specific questions, just post them here and someone may help.

Comment: All you need to do is 1) copy the javareminder class into your project 2) figure out how to start a service 3) figure out how to retrieve current Unix time (it will be a long) and 4) launch time timer task inside your service with the correct time that you've calculated from your NotificationTime-CurrentTime

Comment: didn't want you to make my project. thanks for your time, I will try

Comment: Good luck, I will try to help if you post here.